# Spring boot 2.4.2 external application.yml not read in a Docker container

Tags: spring-boot

Spring Boot:2.4.2 - Cloud version: 2020.0.0 - Java 15 - Docker FROM nginx:1.19.6-alpine

I have my external `application.yml` next to my spring boot jar in a Docker container. This is to **override** some properties.

```sh
springboot.jar
application.yml
```

I have a bash script as an entrypoint which starts the jar

```sh
exec env LOG_FILE=/logs/$APP_NAME/$APP_NAME.log java $opts -jar /opt/app/app.jar &
```

The issue is when Docker starts this container, `springboot.jar` is not reading the external application.yml.

Note that the app starts without any issues. It is just not reading the properties that I want to override.

A very simple example is that in the `application.yml` I intentionally set

```
logging:
  level:
    root: DEBUG
```

Now, my expectation was to see all the debug logs. App did not read it.

**BUT**, if I login to the container and kill the java process and relaunch it myself with the same script mentioned above, it picks up values in the `application.yml`.

The only working solution was launching it with

```sh
-Dspring.config.import=file:/opt/app/application.yml
```

Is this an issue related to 2.4.2 or I'm missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the [Spring Boot Features, section 2.3 External Application Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.2/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-files) the order Spring Boot is looking for application properties is:

1. The classpath root
2. The classpath /config package
3. The current directory
4. The /config subdirectory in the current directory
5. Immediate child directories of the /config subdirectory

Higher defined properties overrides lower defined properties.

So: If you run it via `java $opts -jar /opt/app/app.jar` (you call it with the absolute jar path), be sure that you are in this directory (`cd /opt/app`).

**Example**

Let's say you have the following directory/file structure:

```
.
├── foo
│   └── bin
│       ├── app.jar
│       |   └── application.yml
│       └── application.yml
```

Also given: In the `app.jar`'s `application.yml` `spring.jpa.show-sql` is set to `false`, and in the `application.yml` under the `bin`-directory it is set to `true`.

*Executing inside the `bin` folder*:

```
cd bin
java -jar app.jar
```

In this case, the app runs with `spring.jpa.show-sql` set to `true`, because the `application.yml` of the current directory is found and the property defined in `application.yml` of `app.jar` gets overwritten.

*Executing in another directory*

```
cd bin
cd ..
java -jar bin/app.jar
```

In this case, the app runs with `spring.jpa.show-sql` set to `false`, because in the current directory (the directory OVER `bin`) there is no `application.yml` and so the `application.yml` of the `app.jar` is used.